# Jasypt unable to read literal ampersand on windows?

Tags: powershell, shell, command-prompt, jasypt

Below command:

```
C:\users\xxx\jasypt-1.9.3\bin> ./encrypt.bat password=password input=test.com/test?v=v&w=w
```

complains questions mark ("&") is not allowed. So I tried escaping it as `"&"` or `^&` but Jasypt seemed to strip `&` and what comes after it.

```
C:\users\xxx\jasypt-1.9.3\bin> ./encrypt.bat password=password input=test.com/test?v=v^&w=w
...
----ARGUMENTS-------------------
input: test.com/test?v=v
password: password
...
'w' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How would I make it so that Jasypt reads it as literal ampersand or is this a windows thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell's escape character is `` ` `` (backtick), not `^`**, which is specific to cmd.exe.

However, an *unquoted* `&` is a *metacharacter* (a character with special syntactic meaning) in *both* shells.

Therefore, **to ensure that *PowerShell* passes `&`  through as-is to `./encrypt.bat`, all of the following variations work** (since your argument contains no references to PowerShell variables (`$...`), `"..."` (expandable (interpolating) string) and `'...'` (literal string) can be used interchangeably):

```
./encrypt.bat password=password input=test.com/test?v=v`&w=w
```

```
./encrypt.bat password=password input=test.com/test?v=v"&"w=w
```

```
./encrypt.bat password=password input=test.com/test?v=v'&'w=w
```

```
./encrypt.bat password=password "input=test.com/test?v=v&w=w"
```

```
./encrypt.bat password=password 'input=test.com/test?v=v&w=w'
```

Since you say that it is `./encryp.bat` that complained, **the implication is that `./encrypt.bat` is poorly implemented and doesn't use `"..."` to further process the arguments it receives**, causing `cmd.exe` metacharacters such as `&` to break processing.

To counteract that, you must *additionally* anticipate `cmd.exe`'s escaping needs and include a literal `^` in the argument passed from PowerShell:

```
./encrypt.bat password=password 'input=test.com/test?v=v^&w=w'
```

Comment: I'm curious. Where do you know it's a Powershell issue? I though it's about CMD.

Comment: @Olaf, the form of the prompt string provides the first clue; what unequivocally shows that the batch file is being called from PowerShell is the form `./encrypt.bat`, which wouldn't work from `cmd.exe` (you'd have to use `\ ` , not `/`) - you'd get `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

My experience with the Jasypt's batch files was a little different between a Command Prompt window and a PowerShell session.

**Command Prompt**: `encrypt password=password input=test.com/test?v=v"&"w=w`
(*double-quote the ampersand*)

**PowerShell**: `encrypt password=password input='test.com/test?v=v"&"w=w'`
(*single-quote the string while double-quoting the ampersand*)

---

*(leaving this here for my own sanity as well)*